# Why is my master bedroom light switch turning off the kitchen light?

Tags: electrical, light

It’s a 3 way closet switch, when I flip it up to turn on the closet light on it turns off the kitchen light. The kitchen receptacles are cut off from power and also the kitchen fan aso gets cut off. When I flip the closet light switch down to turn off closet light the kitchen light turns on etc...  The hot wire is connected to the black nut.

[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge images)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138209/discussion-on-question-by-jose-leon-why-is-my-master-bedroom-light-switch-turnin).

Answer (score 6):

Based on a hunch from the comments, I think this is a 3-way switch that *replaced* a regular switch, and that the reason it is a 3-way switch is *not* because a 3-way switch is actually needed, but rather because the original switch had two black wires, one on a screw and the other as a backstab connection, and whoever replaced the switch *assumed* that the three wires (two black, one red) were from a 3-way switch and not "two wires combined together and a third wire separate".

Assuming that's the case, the two black wires should be connected together, just as the screw and backstab are internally connected together. Two ways to do that:

- Add a short piece of 12 AWG black wire (a.k.a. pigtail). Use a wire nut to connect it to the two black wires from the switch and connect it to the black screw on the switch (assuming that there is one black screw and two brass screws - if it is one brass screw and two black screws then connect it to the brass screw). Note that there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a 3-way switch this way as a regular switch. If after doing this you find that the switch seems "upside down", just turn it around or move the red wire to the other (now unused) screw.
- Swap for a high quality regular switch, such as [this Leviton switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Single-Pole-AC-Quiet-Switch-White-R72-05601-2WS/100058788):

[image: Leviton switch with screw to clamp]

The key is a feature called "screw to clamp", though some manufacturers have a fancy name for it. What that lets you do is slide a *straight* wire under each side (top and bottom) of each screw by putting it under a clamp that is tightened when you tighten the screw. That saves the time and trouble of making the wire into a hook *and* it allows you to have two wires on a single screw. The picture is not 100% clear, but it looks like the existing switch may have screw to Clamp. Trim each of the black wires 1/4" and straighten and slide under the clamp, one below the screw, one above, and tighten the screw.

Comment: I agree with everything you said.  But OP stated that the closet light and the kitchen stuff are far away from each other.  If that's case, it does not make sense, at least in my mind, that the original switch was controlling both locations.

Comment: That's the point. The switch wasn't controlling the kitchen. But the hot wire used the switch as a junction.

Comment: OP says the switch was controlling the kitchen.  In one position, the closet light is on and the kitchen stuff off.  In the other position, just the opposite.

Comment: Based on comments, I think that's what it does **now** but that there was a previous switch that didn't affect the kitchen at all

Comment: Okay I did what /manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact told me to do and it had been  resolved. I bought a single  pole switch, connected the red traveler to the top terminal, connected both hot and black traveler to the bottom terminal, connected the ground to ground terminal and walaaa!! It has been fixed. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Now, @JoseLeon — mark this answer as accepted. Congrats on fixing this.

Comment: @JoseLeon - just a note that you're potentially confusing both yourself & others by calling any of those wires "travelers". Only in 3-way (or 4-way) switching circuits are there any wires used as "travelers" - and you don't have that here.

Comment: @brhans This was a cascade effect: 3 wires -> must be 3-way -> 2 of the wires = travelers -> back to regular switch -> *still called them travelers*. So "incorrect, but understandable how OP got there".